# Why does testing `NaN == NaN` not work for dropping from a pandas dataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

Please explain how NaN's are treated in pandas because the following logic seems "broken" to me, I tried various ways (shown below) to drop the empty values.

My dataframe, which I load from a CSV file using `read.csv`, has a column `comments`, which is empty most of the time.

The column `marked_results.comments` looks like this; all the rest of the column is NaN, so pandas loads empty entries as NaNs, so far so good:

```
0       VP
1       VP
2       VP
3     TEST
4      NaN
5      NaN
....
```

Now I try to drop those entries, **only this works:**

- `marked_results.comments.isnull()`

**All these don't work:**

- `marked_results.comments.dropna()` only gives the same column, nothing gets dropped, confusing.
- `marked_results.comments == NaN` only gives a series of all `False`s. Nothing was NaNs... confusing.
- likewise `marked_results.comments == nan`

---

I also tried:

```
comments_values = marked_results.comments.unique()

array(['VP', 'TEST', nan], dtype=object)

# Ah, gotya! so now ive tried:
marked_results.comments == comments_values[2]
# but still all the results are Falses!!!
```

Comment: [NaN != NaN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values) - read Stephen Canon's accepted reply.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use `isnull` and `notnull` to test for NaN (these are more robust using pandas dtypes than numpy), see ["values considered missing" in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#values-considered-missing).

Using the Series method [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html) on a column won't affect the original dataframe, but do what you want:

```
In [11]: df
Out[11]:
  comments
0       VP
1       VP
2       VP
3     TEST
4      NaN
5      NaN

In [12]: df.comments.dropna()
Out[12]:
0      VP
1      VP
2      VP
3    TEST
Name: comments, dtype: object
```

The [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) *DataFrame* method has a subset argument (to drop rows which have NaNs in specific columns):

```
In [13]: df.dropna(subset=['comments'])
Out[13]:
  comments
0       VP
1       VP
2       VP
3     TEST

In [14]: df = df.dropna(subset=['comments'])
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to test `NaN` with `math.isnan()` function (Or `numpy.isnan`). NaNs cannot be checked with the equality operator.

```
>>> a = float('NaN')
>>> a
nan
>>> a == 'NaN'
False
>>> isnan(a)
True
>>> a == float('NaN')
False
```

Help Function ->

```
isnan(...)
    isnan(x) -> bool

    Check if float x is not a number (NaN).
```